# HTML5 Lightbox controls invisible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox

I am using HTML5 video lightbox (https://html5box.com/html5lightbox/index.php). The problem is that when I try to play a local video in full screen mode the controls disappear. They are functional but invisible. Is that a known issue or is it just me?
I have included html5lightbox.js and using it as:

```
<a href="media/video.mp4" class="html5lightbox" title="PDU">
    <img src="media/local_video_poster.png" class="centerImage"/>
</a>
```